# Linker claiming that object is already defined

Tags: c++, namespaces, linker-errors

I have a header file with a namespace, and within that namespace I have several events declared and a single function. Within the corresponding .cpp file, I flesh out the function that would give those objects their properties(the objects are unions). However, when I compile the linker claims that the objects have already been declared in the main.obj, when they have not. I feel like this is a problem with me using a namespace, but I can't find anything pointing to that assumption.

The .h

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>

namespace UserEvents {


    /*Events for the StateMachine*/
     SDL_Event switchToEntryState;
     SDL_Event switchToIntroState;
     SDL_Event switchToGameState;
     SDL_Event switchToPauseState;
     SDL_Event exitState;
     SDL_Event shutdownStateMachine;


    bool initUserStates();
};
```

And the .cpp

```
#include "UserEvents.h"


using namespace UserEvents;
/*

SDL_Event switchToEntryState;
SDL_Event switchToIntroState;
SDL_Event switchToGameState;
SDL_Event switchToPauseState;
SDL_Event exitState;
SDL_Event shutdownStateMachine;

*/

/*
***********************************
USER EVENT CODE CHART
***********************************

EVENT CODE | MODULE
--------------------
0          | STATEMACHINE

*/


bool initUserStates() {
    //Attempt to register the number of events
    Uint32 userEventType = SDL_RegisterEvents(6); //Registering 6 custom events
    if (userEventType!= ((Uint32)-1)) {

        //Set up each event
        SDL_zero(switchToEntryState);
        SDL_zero(switchToIntroState);
        SDL_zero(switchToGameState);
        SDL_zero(switchToPauseState);
        SDL_zero(exitState);
        SDL_zero(shutdownStateMachine);

        switchToEntryState.type = userEventType;
        switchToIntroState.type = userEventType;
        switchToGameState.type = userEventType;
        switchToPauseState.type = userEventType;
        exitState.type = userEventType;
        shutdownStateMachine.type = userEventType;

        switchToEntryState.user.code = 0;
        switchToIntroState.user.code = 0;
        switchToGameState.user.code = 0;
        switchToPauseState.user.code = 0;
        exitState.user.code = 0;
        shutdownStateMachine.user.code = 0;

        switchToEntryState.user.data1 = (void*)0;
        switchToIntroState.user.data1 = (void*)1;
        switchToGameState.user.data1 = (void*)2;
        switchToPauseState.user.data1 = (void*)3;
        exitState.user.data1 = (void*)4;
        shutdownStateMachine.user.data1 = (void*)-1;



        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each file that `#include`s the header file will have its own definition of the objects. That's why there are multiple definitions.

Instead, you should declare the objects as `extern` in the header, and then have a single `.cpp` file that contains those definitions. The `extern` says "This is just a declaration. The object will be defined elsewhere."